# Define custom Class into Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, view

I tried to make my own `DrawingView extends View` into an Activity called `AddCanvasActivity`

, they share many arguments and influence each other, so I thought this would have been a good idea.

The Problem I have:
I am trying to

```
setContentView(R.layout.view_add_canvas);
```

into the `OnCreate` of that activity but I got the following Error Message

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.graphicuss.graphicuss, PID: 3934
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.graphicuss.graphicuss/com.graphicuss.graphicuss.AddCanvasActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.graphicuss.graphicuss.AddCanvasActivity.DrawingView
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.graphicuss.graphicuss.AddCanvasActivity.DrawingView
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.graphicuss.graphicuss.AddCanvasActivity.DrawingView
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.graphicuss.graphicuss.AddCanvasActivity.DrawingView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.graphicuss.graphicuss-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.graphicuss.graphicuss-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.graphicuss.graphicuss-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.graphicuss.graphicuss-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.graphicuss.graphicuss-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.graphicuss.graphicuss-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.graphicuss.graphicuss-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.graphicuss.graphicuss-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.graphicuss.graphicuss-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.graphicuss.graphicuss-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.graphicuss.graphicuss-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.graphicuss.graphicuss-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.graphicuss.graphicuss-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
```

and so on because of that line where I try to `setContentView.`

In my XML
     `view_add_canvas`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    tools:context=".AddCanvasActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:minWidth="400dp" />

        <com.graphicuss.graphicuss.AddCanvasActivity.DrawingView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/DrawingViewAddCanvas"
            class="com.graphicuss.graphicuss.AddCanvasActivity.DrawingView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Hier Zeichnen" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

... there I wanted to load that `DrawingView` Element, which was defined in the Activity i mentioned.
Do I have to add it to the Manifest anyhow?

Update #1:
The whole `ShowAllActivity` including the `DrawingView`

```
public class DrawingView extends View {

    public int width;
    public int height;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mBitmapPaint;
    Context context;
    private Paint circlePaint;
    private Path circlePath;
    private Path mPreviewPath;
    private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;
    private float mStartX;
    private float mStartY;
    private float mDistanceX;
    private float mDistanceY;
    private float mDistance;
    private float radiusPreview;
    private Paint clearPaint;

    public DrawingView(Context c) {
        super(c);
        Log.d("ADDCANVAS - DrawingView", "OnCreate1");
        context = c;
        mPath = new Path();
        mPreviewPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        clearPaint = new Paint();
        circlePaint = new Paint();
        circlePath = new Path();
        circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
        clearPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);


    }

    public DrawingView(Context c, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(c,attributeSet);
        Log.d("ADDCANVAS - DrawingView", "OnCreate2");
        context = c;
        mPath = new Path();
        mPreviewPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        clearPaint = new Paint();
        circlePaint = new Paint();
        circlePath = new Path();
        circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
        clearPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);


    }

    public DrawingView(Context c, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyle) {
        super(c,attributeSet,defStyle);
        Log.d("ADDCANVAS - DrawingView", "OnCreate3");
        context = c;
        mPath = new Path();
        mPreviewPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        clearPaint = new Paint();
        circlePaint = new Paint();
        circlePath = new Path();
        circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
        clearPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        Log.d("ADDCANVAS- DrawingView", "OnSizeChanged");
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(!mFinished) {
        Log.d("ADDCANVAS- DrawingView", "OnDraw");
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        if (mDrawOption == "pencil" || mDrawOption == "line") canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(circlePath, circlePaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPreviewPath, mPaint);
        }


    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        Log.d("ADDCANVAS- DrawingView", "TouchStart");

        mStartX = x;
        mStartY = y;

        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        Log.d("ADDCANVAS- DrawingView", "TouchMove");


        float dx = abs(x - mX);
        float dy = abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mDistanceX = abs(x - mStartX);
            mDistanceY = abs(y - mStartY);
            mDistance = (float) sqrt((mDistanceX * mDistanceX) + (mDistanceY * mDistanceY));
            mPreviewPath.reset();

            switch (mDrawOption) {
                case "circle":
                    mPreviewPath.addCircle(mStartX, mStartY, mDistance, Path.Direction.CW);
                    break;
                case "pencil":
                    mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
                    break;
                case "ellipse":
                    mPreviewPath.addOval(mStartX, mStartY, x, y, Path.Direction.CW);
                    break;
                case "line":
                    mPreviewPath.moveTo(mStartX, mStartY);
                    mPreviewPath.quadTo(mStartX, mStartY, x, y);
                    break;
                case "rectangle":
                    if (mStartX > x) {
                        if (mStartY > y) {
                            mPreviewPath.addRect(x, y, mStartX, mStartY, Path.Direction.CW);
                        } else mPreviewPath.addRect(x, mStartY, mStartX, y, Path.Direction.CW);
                    }
                    if (mStartY > y) {
                        mPreviewPath.addRect(mStartX, y, x, mStartY, Path.Direction.CW);
                    }
                    mPreviewPath.addRect(mStartX, mStartY, x, y, Path.Direction.CW);
                    break;
                case "text":
                    //to be done
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
            mX = x;
            mY = y;


            circlePath.reset();
            circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
        }
    }


    private void touch_up(float x, float y) {
        Log.d("ADDCANVAS- DrawingView", "TouchUp");
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        mDistanceX = abs(x - mStartX);
        mDistanceY = abs(y - mStartY);
        mDistance = (float) sqrt((mDistanceX * mDistanceX) + (mDistanceY * mDistanceY));
        Path pa = new Path();

        Log.d("DrawOption: State", mDrawOption);

        switch (mDrawOption) {
            case "circle":
                mCanvas.drawCircle(mStartX, mStartY, mDistance, mPaint);
                pa.addCircle(mStartX,mStartY,mDistance,Path.Direction.CW);
                Log.d("DrawOption", "Circle, Touch up");
                Log.d("DrawOption: Dist", Float.toString(mDistance));
                Log.d("DrawOption: DistX", Float.toString(mDistanceX));
                Log.d("DrawOption: DistY", Float.toString(mDistanceY));
                Log.d("DrawOption: mX", Float.toString(mX));
                Log.d("DrawOption: mX", Float.toString(mY));
                break;
            case "rectangle":
                mCanvas.drawRect(mStartX, mStartY, x, y, mPaint);
                if (mStartX > x) {
                    if (mStartY > y) {
                       pa.addRect(x, y, mStartX, mStartY, Path.Direction.CW);
                    } else pa.addRect(x, mStartY, mStartX, y, Path.Direction.CW);
                }
                if (mStartY > y) {
                    pa.addRect(mStartX, y, x, mStartY, Path.Direction.CW);
                }
                pa.addRect(mStartX, mStartY, x, y, Path.Direction.CW);
                break;
            case "ellipse":
                mCanvas.drawOval(mStartX, mStartY, x, y, mPaint);
                pa.addOval(mStartX,mStartY,x,y,Path.Direction.CW);
                break;
            case "line":
                mCanvas.drawLine(mStartX, mStartY, x, y, mPaint);
                break;

            case "text":
                mCanvas.drawText("Text", mX, mY, mPaint);
                break;

            case "pencil":
                mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
                pa.addPath(mPath);
                break;
            default:
                Log.d("DrawOption: default", mDrawOption);

        }
        PathInformation pi = new PathInformation(pa, true, mPaint);
        Log.d("before add path color", Integer.toString(mPaint.getColor()));
        mPathsArray.addPath(pi);

        circlePath.reset();
        mPreviewPath.reset();
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        // mCanvas.drawPath(mPath,  mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(!mFinished) {

            Log.d("ADDCANVAS- DrawingView", "onTouchEvent");

            Log.d("TouchEvent true", Float.toString(event.getX()));
            Log.d("TouchEvent true", Float.toString(event.getY()));

            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
        else {
            Log.d("TouchEvent false", Float.toString(event.getX()));
            Log.d("TouchEvent false", Float.toString(event.getY()));
            return false;
        }
    }


    public void undoLastPath() {
        boolean b = mPathsArray.undoLast();
        if(b) {
            mCanvas.drawRect(0, 0, mCanvas.getWidth(), mCanvas.getHeight(), clearPaint);
            invalidate();
            for (int i = 0; i <= mPathsArray.getLength(); i++) {
                if (mPathsArray.getPathInfo(i).getValid() == true) {
                    mCanvas.drawPath(mPathsArray.getPathInfo(i).getPath(), mPathsArray.getPathInfo(i).getPaint());
                    Log.d("Undolastpath paint", Integer.toString(mPathsArray.getPathInfo(i).getPaint().getColor()));
                }
            }
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please Post DrawingView class

Comment: "they share many arguments and influence each other, so I thought this would have been a good idea." – To use a nested class in a layout, it must be `public static`, so I think it's not going to work as you'd hoped.

Comment: @ItzikSamar I did, Update #1

Comment: @MikeM. I am using many non-static fields to define the shapes I am drawing on the canvas or is there a way to "make them" static?

Comment: There is no need for DrawingView source ... the point is where it is defined (package and eventually outer class) ... are you sure that the package 
 name is `com.graphicuss.graphicuss.AddCanvasActivity` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. Do you mean you're using `ShowAllActivity`'s fields in `DrawingView`? If so, then you don't want to do that. Create setters in `DrawingView` to pass the necessary data. If that's not what you mean, then there's really no reason to nest `DrawingView` in `ShowAllActivity` anyway, and it'd be easier to pull it out into its own top-level class.

Comment: also it is not possible for inflater to create non static inner class

Comment: First of all:thanks for your help! I did not know that.
@MikeM. Yes, it wasnt as complicated as i thought to separate the class and the activity but now somehow the setColor of the mPaint element does not work anymore.

Comment: Oops, never mind. I see it now. Mistyped the ctrl+f. Anyway, I don't see where you're calling `setColor()` on `mPaint`. I also don't see where it's declared.